# ember data not loading belongsTo model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember 2.8.0 and ember-data 2.8.0. I have the following models defined:

```
//app/models/store.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    floor: DS.belongsTo('floor'),
    number: DS.attr('string'),
    phone: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    photo: DS.attr(),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});

//app/models/floor.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    stores: DS.hasMany('store'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

My **router.js** has the following routes:

```
//app/router.js
this.route('stores', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit');
});
```

My **templates/stores/index.hbs** has the following `{{#each}}` statement:

```
<tbody>
      {{#each model as |store|}}
       <tr>
           <td>{{store.name}}</td>
           <td>{{store.number}}</td>
           <td>{{store.floor.name}}</td>
           <td>{{store.phone}}</td>
           <td>{{store.email}}</td>
           <td>{{moment-format store.createdAt}}</td>
           <td>{{moment-format store.updatedAt}}</td>   
       </tr>
       {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I would have expected that the line `{{store.floor.name}}` would have made a request to /floors/{id} for each and every row in the table.

What am I missing?
What's the proper way to handle that in Ember?

Should my api return something different than the below?

```
[{"id":1,"floorId":1,"name":"McDonalds","number":"10-A","phone":"(11) 2020-3455","email":"lapa@mcdonalds.com.br","photo":null,"createdAt":"2016-09-15T13:45:32.000Z","updatedAt":"2016-09-15T13:45:32.000Z"}]
```

Should I use other model hooks to load the associated model manually?

Comment: The attribute names of your `store` model need to match what the server gives you, unless you have defined some special processing for them in adapters/serializers/somewhere (I forget where exactly this happens, now), which seems unlikely. So, return `floor` instead of `floorId` and things may just begin to work.

Comment: spot on @Thernys, thank you! Interestingly, changing what my api returns fixes it, however, changing my model's property name from `floor` to `floorId` doesn't. Would that be some ember-data convention thingy? Also, care to answer the question?

Comment: Also found where you can customize the processing as you mentioned @Thernys: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_relationships

Comment: You are missing { async: true } on the relationship.

Comment: @user2105103 nope, since ember 2.x this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As initially (and naughtily) answered in the comments, the attribute names of your `store` model are expected to match what the server gives you, unless you have [defined custom processing for them in your serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-serializers/). So, return `floor` instead of `floorId` and things may just begin to work.

I'm not entirely certain why it didn't work for you to change the attribute name to match server results instead (`floor: DS... => floorId: DS...`). As far as I can tell it should work that way as well (as in, when I tried just now). I like to take the [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) approach, so with the limited information available I'm going to assume your test conditions simply may have been flawed. Perhaps you had already modified the server to return `floor`, which no longer matched the model's expectations. Maybe you forgot to change `{{store.floor.name}}` in your template to match new definitions. Maybe you just forgot to rebuild your project if using Ember-CLI.

<sup><sub>Or maybe I just have no idea what I'm talking about and you should ask a new question if you care enough and have attempted to rule out user error.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

The way ember-data expects the data from your backend depends on your serializer. You didn't specified which serializer you use, so I can not tell you what it expects. But the format that is expected by ember-data internally is [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org). So for your case this would be right:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "store",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "McDonalds",
        "number": "10-A",
        "phone": "(11) 2020-3455",
        "email": "lapa@mcdonalds.com.br",
        "photo": null,
        "createdAt": "2016-09-15T13:45:32.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-09-15T13:45:32.000Z"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "floor": {
          "data": {
            "type": "floor",
            "id":"1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure that your serializer returns this format for your backend response.